# Meaning of symbol |

Tags: notation

I'm looking for the meaning of this line: $q_i | 1$.

It should be related to dividers of a number or prime numbers.

If this is not enough information then please leave a comment because the proof it's from is written in dutch so I'll need to translate it first before I can show it.

I tried looking for this on the web and on stackexchange but the search functions don't search for | so I'm not able to find my probably simple answer.

Comment: $a|b$ usually means "$a$ divides $b$".

Comment: it means divides. In particular, that there exists some $x_i \in \mathbb Z$ so that $1=q_ix_i$

Comment: $q_{\mid A}$ also means the map $q$ restricted to the set $A$.

Comment: Two different uses than yours, but ones widely used:  In probability and statistics, "$P(a|b)$" means the probability of $a$ *given* that $b$ is the case, or *conditioned* on $b$.  In formal logic:  it is called the "Sheffer stroke" meaning "not both" as in $a|b$ is the logical statement that not both $a$ and $b$ are true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a|b$ means $a$ divides $b$, or rather $b$ is divisible by $a$. This means that $b=aq$ for some $a, q \in \mathbb{Z}$. The restriction that $a,q$ should be integers depends on the fields of mathematics you are in, and some times is not present.

For example, $5|15$, *i.e.* $5$ divides $15$, or $15$ is divisible by $5$. In deed, $15=5*3$. In this case, $a=5$, $b=15$, $q=3$.

In the universe of integer numbers, $q_1|1$ implies that $q_1=\pm1$. It is in deed the case that $1$ is only divisible by itself and $-1$. If you are studying discrete mathematics, for example, which only deals with integers, this is the meaning of it.

Answer (score -1):

it means divides, eg 2|6. if $q_{i} | 1$ then $q_{i} = \pm 1$

Comment: This is not true in, say, $\Bbb Z[i]$ where we have $6$ units (not only $\pm 1$).

Comment: This is true in $\mathbb{Z}$ but not in a general ring.

Comment: I thought we were working in Z